# Accessing local SQS service from another docker container using environment variables

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose, boto3, amazon-sqs

I have a flask application which needs to interact with an SQS service whenever an endpoint is hit.
I'm mimicing the SQS service locally using docker image `sukumarporeddy/sqs:fp` whose base image is https://github.com/vsouza/docker-SQS-local with two more queues added in configuration.

I need to access this service from another **app** which is run as **app_service**. These two services are run using **docker-compose.yml** file where I mentioned two services.

**app_service**

**sqs_service**

While building the **app** image, I'm setting environment variables to access the **sqs_service** as `QUEUE_ENDPOINT=http://sqs_service:9324`. But when I try to access the **sqs_service** the app, it is saying invalid queue endpoint.

I'm using **boto3** to connect to the local **sqs_service**.

```
boto3.client('sqs', endpoint_url=os.getenv("QUEUE_ENDPOINT"), region_name='default')
```

Here's the **docker-compose.yml** file.

```
  app_service:
    container_name: app_container
    restart: always
    image: app
    build: 
      context: ./dsdp
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.app.local
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    env_file:
        - ./local_secrets.env
    command: flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port 5000

  sqs_service:
    container_name: sqs_container
    image: sukumarporeddy/sqs:fp
    ports:
      - "9324:9324"
```

**local_secrets.env:**

```
QUEUE_ENDPOINT=https://sqs_service:9324
FEEDER_QUEUE_URL=https://sqs_service:9324/queue/feeder
PREDICTION_QUEUE_URL=https://sqs_service:9324/queue/prediction
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=''
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=''
```

Error that I'm getting when trying to send messages to the SQS service that is running locally.

> ValueError
>
> ValueError: Invalid endpoint: https://sqs_service:9324

Where am I making mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow I was not able to use the SQS queue using the service name mentioned in the environment variables. 
This is what I did instead.

Got the service name from environment variables, got the IP address of the service using **socket** library in python and used the IP address to format and create the QUEUE endpoint url.

```
import socket
queue_endpoint_service = os.getenv("QUEUE_ENDPOINT_SERVICE")
queue_endpoint_port = os.getenv("QUEUE_ENDPOINT_PORT")
feeder_queue = os.getenv("FEEDER_QUEUE")
prediction_queue = os.getenv("PREDICTION_QUEUE")
queue_endpoint_ip = socket.gethostbyname(queue_endpoint_service)
queue_endpoint = f"http://{queue_endpoint_ip}:{queue_endpoint_port}"
mc = boto3.client('sqs', endpoint_url=queue_endpoint, region_name='default')
feeder_queue_url = f"{queue_endpoint}/queue/{feeder_queue}"
prediction_queue_url = f"{queue_endpoint}/queue/{prediction_queue}"
```

I'm able to send the messages now by hitting the endpoints in flask app.

**Note:** Also used the new docker image which **Adiii** mentioned. Not using the old image anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no configuration for SSL in your docker-compose file, so the issue with might be with `https`. try to change `https` to `http`.

```
QUEUE_ENDPOINT=http://sqs_service:9324
FEEDER_QUEUE_URL=http://sqs_service:9324/queue/feeder
PREDICTION_QUEUE_URL=http://sqs_service:9324/queue/prediction
```

Also, try to call SQS container by name without using ENV for debugging.

```
import boto3
sqs=boto3.client('sqs', endpoint_url="http://sqs_service:9324", region_name='default')
# Create a SQS queue
response = sqs.create_queue(
    QueueName='SQS_QUEUE_NAME',
    Attributes={
        'DelaySeconds': '60',
        'MessageRetentionPeriod': '86400'
    }
)

print(response['QueueUrl'])
```

Tested with [alpine-sqs](https://hub.docker.com/r/roribio16/alpine-sqs/) image.

Comment: Still same error even after changing `https` to `http`.

`ValueError
ValueError: Invalid endpoint: http://sqs_service:9324`

Comment: I am not sure about image, if it some thing to do with image. but tested with https://hub.docker.com/r/roribio16/alpine-sqs/ and working fine

Comment: can you confirm that the service is running in your container?

Comment: Let me try the same with new image that you've suggested.

Comment: Still no luck even after changing the docker image and even after trying to access the endpoints directly in code instead of env variables.

Comment: That's great that you made it work. as i tested with `sqs=boto3.client('sqs', endpoint_url="http://localhost:9324", region_name='default')` so might be that case with service name. script was on host and the sqs was running in container

Comment: I'm still wondering why it's not able to access the sqs_service which is set in environment variable.